# 4 Gridded Prime Numbers

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

You have the first four prime numbers ($2$,$3$,$5$ and $7$) which are gridded and shown as below:

[image]

You are trying to get highest total score you can reach with arranging the  numbers by rotating (no reflection allowed) them without overlapping them on each other.

The total score is calculated how many lines are joint after arranging and multiplying how many joints you got with the actual prime number and take the sum of all gridded prime number scores at the end. For example, if this question was asked to arrange the first two prime numbers ($2$ and $3$), the answer would be as below:

[image]

Since there are 8 lines of the grid are touched with each other, the total score would be $2\times8+3\times8=40$ which is the maximum score you can get with $2$ and $3$.

**Note:** I am very sorry to let you know there is better answer than 172. That's totally my mistake!

Comment: It is definitely not clear how score is computed. Ah Got It, when you mentioned 8 lines you should have noted that the picture is actually also 8 lines high. XD

Comment: i'm sorry...did you mean to say "there is no better answer than 172"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have 172, with the correct tiles.

> [image]

Comment: also, just rotate the 2 clockwise 90 degrees for an extra 5 points

Comment: For anyone interested in trying to beat this, I made [a spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k2b46yo2oQnbfSO8_3xshAbVZ1md0N_hVrsb9T3ob_g/edit?usp=sharing) to make it easier to play around with.  Make a copy for yourself and try to beat 172!

Comment: Thanks for that spreadsheet. I tried lots of combinations but I have no idea how to get more than 172.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Nicely made! I wrote a small macro to utilize the spreadsheet and brute-force possible solutions. Can't get past 172.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the maximum is

> 172

Otherwise I think the maximum cannot be found by a greedy approach (trying to maximize the contact point between numbers.

My alternative solution to Matsmath:

> [image]

Comment: Isn't your solution the same as mine, just rotated 180 degrees (essentially: turned upside down)?

Comment: oh men, you are right. I spent 1 hour on that _-_

Answer (score 2):

I got

> 176

With this formation:

> [image]

Comment: 7 is wrong shape.

Comment: Alright, how about now? Edited the answer

Comment: @Oray interchanged 5 and 2 because 2's rotation just did not seem right. Score is still the same.

Comment: How is this accepted and bountied when the 7 is reflected, which the puzzle statement expressly does not allow? @Oray

Comment: @Rubio that's totally my mistake sorry :/

Comment: @Rubio I did not notice that. I apologize.

Comment: @Oray Is it still correct that there is an answer that is more than 172, with no reflection allowed?

Comment: You could just reflect the entire thing.

Comment: @Deusovi If you reflect the entire thing, 2 and 5 would swap place and the  score will be lowered (158).

Comment: @max8126: Ah, good point - my mistake!

Answer (score 1):

I have

> $166$

With

> [image: primes together]
>  $2\times 6 + 3\times 8 + 5\times 12 + 7\times 10 = 166$

Comment: that is $6*9 + 4*12 + 8*8 = 166$

Comment: Yes it should be $166$, I had missed one of the seven edges in the count.

Answer (score 0):

I got

> <strike>182</strike> 146

With this formation:

> [image: prime grid]

EDIT: Miscalculated the score.